# Delete matching files created more than 10 days ago, but with an excepion

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm working on a simple batch script where I need to delete .txt files older than 10 days from a directory, but with an exception: I want to retain any .txt files created today.

The script should scan the directory for .txt files, check their creation date, and delete those that are older than 10 days, except for files created today.

I tried with the code below, however, it doesn't work for me.

```bash
@echo off

echo Checking if today's date file exists...
forfiles /p "C:\Test" /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE if @fdate==%DATE% echo Today's date file found"

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Deleting outdated .txt files older than 10 days.
    forfiles /p "%targetDirectory%" /s /m *.txt /d -%olderThanDays% /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo Deleting outdated .txt: @file & del @file"
)
```

Could someone provide a sample batch script or guidance on how to achieve this specific file deletion logic in a Windows environment?

Comment: Mmm... A file created today is _not_ "older than 10 days", so What is the exception?  *`:/`*

Comment: New files are generated daily, while those older than 10 days need to be removed.

Comment: You seem not to have understood @SergiejKlimentowski. There is no exception, because today's files can never be older than ten days. So all you are effectively wanting is to delete all which were created more that ten days ago. I should mention however that `forfiles.exe` uses only the modified date and time stamp, not the creation date and time stamp.

Comment: Let's say a folder containing 10 files. Every day at 10 PM, a new file is generated, bringing the total count to 11. At 10:30 PM, a batch script runs and deletes the oldest file in the folder, ensuring that no file remains older than 10 days. If the new file fails to generate, the script checks if the new file exists and, if not, do nothing.

Comment: So, you want to delete files older than 10 days, but retain files with 10 days, and with 9 days, and with 8 days, and with 7 days, and with 6 days, and with 5 days, and with 4 days, and with 3 days, and with 2 days, and with 1 day, and with 0 days (created today)... That is _a lot_ of exceptions! **`;)`**

Comment: I'm a complete beginner. What seems like one exception to me translates to ten exceptions for a program 

Comment: No! I listed all these "exceptions" in order for you to realize that no one of such exceptions are really exceptions! Nor the 9 days, nor the rest, **nor the created today one**! So there is not any reason for you to explícitly say that the "created today" files _is_ an exception! It is not. The created today files are _also_ included in the "older than 10 days" rule...

Comment: You also need to clarify whether the modification date and time is okay for you or not. Technically, depending upon when this script runs, the created and modification times of todays 'generated file' is very likely to be the same, although that is less likely with the previous ones. Not knowing how to script or code this is not an excuse for not being able to fully describe the task and requirement details. Your task appears to now be slightly different, you seem to only want to delete the 'too old' file(s), if a file exists which has a created, _(or possibly modified)_, date matching today.

Comment: Also, depending upon how and when this script is run, you may be better advised to just maintain the most recently created, _(or modified)_, ten files.

Comment: If your first line is `@Echo Off`, your second is `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\Test" /S /M "*.txt" /D +0 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE Echo Found @Path\"" 1>NUL 2>&1` and a third `If ErrorLevel 1 Pause & Exit /B`, then any lines beneath that will only be reached if there is at least one file modified today.